# Input fields showing weird behaviour on Android Chrome

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I have very simple markup, just a few input fields:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                              
<html>                                                                       
    <head>                                                                   
            <title>Test</title>                                              
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
            <link href="css/style.css" media="(max-width: 60em)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>                                                                  
    <body>                                                                   
            <div id="signup-home-div">                                       
                    <a href="home">Home</a>                                  
            </div>                                                           

            <div id="signup-form-div">                                       
                    <form id="signup-form" action="#">                       
                            <div id="signup-name-div">                       
                                    <div id="signup-name-label">Name</div>   
                                    <input type="text" id="signup-name" name="name"/>
                            </div>                                           

                            <div id="signup-email-div">                      
                                    <div id="signup-email-label">Email</div> 
                                    <input type="text" id="signup-email" name="email"/>
                            </div>                                           

                            <div id="signup-captcha-div">                    
                                    <div id="signup-captcha-label">          
                                            Enter the text in the image.     
                                    </div>                                   
                                    <img id="signup-captcha-img" alt="" src=""/>
                                    <input type="text" id="signup-captcha" name="captcha"/>
                            </div>                                           

                            <div id="signup-div">                            
                                    <button class='btn' id="signup" type="button">Sign Up!</button>
                                    <div id="signup-status"></div>           
                            </div>                                           
                    </form> 
            </div>                                                           

            <div id="signup-response-div">                                   
            </div>                                                           
    </body>                                                                  
</html>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
html, body, ul, ol {                                                         
    margin : 0;                                                              
    padding : 0;                                                             
    border : 0;                                                              
}                                                                            
body {                                                                       
    width : 100%;                                                            
    box-sizing: border-box;                                                  
}                                                                            
body {                                                                       
    background : #06509b;                                                    
    font-family : "Open Sans", sans-serif;                                   
}                                                                            
.btn, .img-btn, .link {                                                      
    background-color : #06509b;                                              
    color : #f6f6f6;                                                         
    border : 1px solid #3a82cd;                                              
    height : 2em;                                                            
    line-height : 2;                                                         
}                                                                            
.img-btn {                                                                   
    background-color : #f6f6f6;                                              
    color : #06509b;                                                         
}                                                                            
.link {                                                                      
    text-decoration : none;                                                  
    padding : 0.5em;                                                         
}                                                                            
.btn:hover, .img-btn:hover, .link:hover, .btn:focus, .img-btn:focus, .link:focus {
    background-color : #3a82cd;                                              
}                                                                            

#signup-home-div {                                                           
    margin-top : 10%;                                                        
    margin-left : 70%;                                                       
}                                                                            
#signup-home-div a {                                                         
    color : #ef8f00;
    font-size : large;                                                       
    text-decoration : none;                                                  
}                                                                            
#signup-form-div {                                                           
    width : 70%;                                                             
    margin-top : 5%;                                                         
    margin-left : 15%;                                                       
    border : 1px solid #cccccc;                                              
    padding : 0.5em;                                                         
    padding-bottom : 0.25em;                                                 
    color : #f6f6f6;                                                         
    font-family : "Open Sans", sans-serif;                                   
    font-size : 100%;                                                        
}                                                                            
form {                                                                       
    width : 100%;                                                            
}                                                                            
#signup-name-div, #signup-email-div, #signup-pubname-div, #signup-div, #signup-captcha-div {
    width : 90%;                                                             
    margin-left : 5%;                                                        
    margin-bottom : 1em;                                                     
}                                                                            
#signup-name, #signup-email, #signup-pubname, #signup-captcha {              
    border : 1px solid #cccccc;                                              
    width : 100%;                                                            
    height : 2em;                                                            
    color : #666666;                                                         
}                                                                            
#signup-status {                                                             
    width : 100%;                                                            
    height : 1em;                                                            
    margin-top : 0.5em;                                                      
    text-align : center;                                                     
    font-style : italic;                                                     
    display : none;                                                          
}                                                                            
#signup {                                                                    
    width : 40%;
   margin-top : 0.5em;                                                      
    margin-left : 30%;                                                       
}                                                                            
#signup-response-div {                                                       
    width : 70%;                                                             
    margin-top : 10%;                                                        
    margin-left : 15%;                                                       
    border : 1px solid #cccccc;                                              
    padding : 1em;                                                           
    text-align : center;                                                     
    white-space : normal;                                                    
    display : none;                                                          
    color : #f6f6f6;                                                         
}                                                                            
#signup-captcha-img {                                                        
    width : 100%;                                                            
}                                                                            
#signup-name-label, #signup-email-label, #signup-pubname-label, #signup-captcha-label {
    margin-bottom : 0.5em;                                                   
}
```

I tested this on MotoG (4.4.4) with Chrome. Initially the page looks and behaves as expected. Specifically I am not able to scroll horizontally. However when I click on any of the input fields, the soft keyboard pops up and at that moment the whole layout seems to jump. I try to enter a few letters and close the keyboard. Now somehow the page acquires the ability to scroll horizontally. Also immediately after closing the keyboard there is an ugly glitch where layout seems to be redrawn.After clicking on input fields couple of times, the page seems to freeze. Very annoying! I have thought hard but can't figure out what is going on. If you want to quickly try on your mobile, the page is also available at: http://bugtest.everydayapps.in.

Edit:
I am OK with the whole page scrolling up which in any case cannot be avoided AFAIK, but the page jumping sideways is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a wrapper div around everything inside the body

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
   all your content here
</div>
</body>

#wrapper
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```